# iPhone playback quiet after microphone use

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audio

I'm using an `AVSpeechSynthesizer` in my app to synthesise text to speech and play it back on the iPhone's speakers. All works well.
After that I want to recognise the users speech and I'm using [SwiftSpeech](https://github.com/Cay-Zhang/SwiftSpeech) to do so. It uses `SFSpeechRecognizer` under the hood. Everything is good here too.
After that the output from speech synthesis (doing it just like before with `AVSpeechSynthesizer`) is really quiet.
And when the iPhone is connected to a bluetooth headset and it played back via the headphones fine, after doing the speech recognition, the audio output switched from the BT headset to the iPhone (again really quiet.)

I couldn't find anything about that online.

I don't know if sample code would be any helpful, let me know tho.